# Getting feedback from a computer

Tags: learning, digital-piano

Is there a way of obtaining a feedback from a computer about what I play on  a digital piano?

The purpose is to learn, and although I'd prefer real-time feedback, any sort of feedback would be useful. Saving the result of my drills and getting it through a program would also be interesting.

It's clear that that won't substitute a teacher, specially when it's about why something is wrong, and not only what is different. But it could be an inexpensive form of learning.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at MuseScore, a free open source music composition tool.  I use it for composition, although I haven't tried using MIDI input yet.  However, it does support it.  Have a look at this to see for yourself:

Comment: I agree with the MuseScore suggestion and I can confirm that it works well via MIDI over USB, In fact one of our setups here is set up with a Casio digital piano and Musescore for composition.

Comment: Nice!  I'll have to try it sometime; keying in notes on the computer keyboard or dragging them with a mouse is pretty tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the recent digital pianos feature USB MIDI interface that allows to connect instrument and computer through USB cable. Usually this allows to transfer data both from (read keystrokes) and to (play commands) the digital piano.

One or another MIDI-capable software surely can do that you need. You may check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MIDI_editors_and_sequencers) for the most widely known MIDI tools.